# During string concatenation, how to add delimiter only if variable is set?

Tags: python

How to add the delimiter only if that variable has a value, in the below code, I am trying to avoid 2 underscores like: `foo_bar__baz`, a,b,d will be always set, only c is optional, is there a more pythonic way?

```
>>> a_must='foo'
>>> b_must='bar'
>>> c_optional=''
>>> d_must='baz'
>>>
>>> f'{a_must}_{b_must}_{c_optional}_{d_must}' if c_optional else 
f'{a_must}_{b_must}_{d_must}'
'foo_bar_baz'
```

Its in python3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the conditional inside the `f-string` itself:

```
f'{a_must}_{b_must}_{c_optional+"_" if c_optional else ""}{d_must}'
```

Output:

```
'foo_bar_baz'
```

Answer (score 3):

To be a little more flexible, something like this would work:

```
variables = [a_must, b_must, c_optional, d_must]
'_'.join([x for x in variables if x])
```

Comment: This won't work if one of the required variables contains a falsey value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are pointing out. Could you elaborate? I might be missing something obvious!

Comment: I meant that if, for example, `b_must` is set with an empty string, then the output would be missing the `_` delimiter for `b_must` even though it is a required variable. But then upon rereading the question, I realized that the OP means that variables such as `b_must` will always have a non-empty value, so my concern is invalid after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list of tokens and use `str.join` to join the list into a string with `_` as the delimiter:

```
tokens = [a_must, b_must]
if c_optional:
     tokens.append(c_optional)
tokens.append(d_must)
print('_'.join(tokens))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works fine, it just needed a little formatting. I added the print statement for testing.

```
a_must='foo'
b_must='bar'
c_optional=''
d_must='baz'

if c_optional:
  result = f'{a_must}_{b_must}_{c_optional}_{d_must}'
else:
  result = f'{a_must}_{b_must}_{d_must}'

print(result)
```